# Replace Spaces and Dashes and Format Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

A few days back I had asked a similar question for replacing spaces in XSLT , but now I am facing another issue within the same code.

Previously Asked:
So I have to export data from our application, now for doing that I wrote XML code and while exporting certain fields need to be formatted for which i am using XSLT. Now the issue here is in my SQL SERVER database I have a contact number field, some of the number are in the format 1234567890 while some have spaces 123 456 7890. So now when I am using the below mentioned xslt code, everything is working as expected if the field has spaces but messes up when it does not have spaces. I know I can make changes in the database directly but that will not be permanent solution. If anyone could provide some guidance it would be great. Solution was as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="phone" select="translate(D_PHONE, ' ', '')" />  
<xsl:value-of select="concat('(', substring($phone, 1, 3), ') ', substring($phone, 4, 3), '-', substring($phone, 7, 4))" />
```

But now the issue is some of the fields are coming back as 123-456-7890 with dashes instead of spaces and this solution does fail because of that. Is there a replace tag where I can basically mention all the characters that I want to replace in the field and then format them as previously ?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just add `-` to the [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)? `translate(D_PHONE, ' -', '')`

Comment: And no, XSLT, has no `replace` element *per se*, though it could be argued that that's a subset of what a template can do.

Comment: There is no space with the dash. So the phone numbers can either be 1234567890, 123 456 7890 or 123-456-7890

Comment: Did you try it?? Maybe read the spec I linked to to learn how translate works.

Comment: I did not try it just yet, but I will let you know as soon as I run and it have some results

Comment: @DanielHaley - Just wanted to let you know that i tried  running the xml and it worked fine. It did properly format the phone number and I did get my expected results. Thank u so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could add **all** unwanted characters to the `translate()` function that translates them to an empty string (IOW, removes them).

For example, this removes both spaces and hyphens:

```
<xsl:variable name="phone" select="translate(D_PHONE, ' -', '')" />
```

---

Alternatively, you could define the variable so that only digits are retained:

```
<xsl:variable name="phone" select="translate(D_PHONE, translate(D_PHONE, '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
```

Comment: Nice trick for retaining only characters from a specified set.